# Restore an etcd cluster in a Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, etcd

I want to deploy a etcd cluster using a Helm Chart with the possibility to restore in case of a cluster-level failure.

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/etcd

Deployment using the following Helm Chart works fine - I can use it with success as a storage backend for my application, the problem is - I can't restore it from a snapshot. Tried to restore it, but every time a spin up a new cluster, exec into it and try to restore the snapshot (copied into the pod), the data is not restored. Or in other words - I see that the data folder is re-created inside the pod, but still, no data is inserted, looks like etcd is still using the  "default.etcd" data folder, which is mounted as the default PVC, instead of a "restored.etcd".

Any one had similar issues with restoring an etcd helm chart data on a k8s cluster? Any tips?

Comment: What commands are you using to backup/restore snapshots?

Comment: Hi, what k8s version do You have? Have You tried with [`StatefulSets`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/)?